# Owin Middleware for the Authentication,during the windows service host

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, identityserver3

I'm hosting my web API which is of Class library project type using windows service and OWIN. The web API got hosted but the OWIN middle wares were not added to the IAppBuilder. When i tried with the web API of ASP.NET Web Application project type. Its been added to the IAppBuilder. Is there any thing i should do to add the middle wares for the Class library project . Because of the this I'm not able to validate the access Token and the claims transformation .

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: im just using WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080") . What i found out is that when i host the web Api from the Owin WebApp.Start. The Owin Middleware which is responisble for the authentication were not added to the IAppBuilder. And it doesn't matter what project type it is.